# How do I use CFRetain and CFRelease properly?

Tags: objective-c, memory-management

Here's some sample code:

```
@interface Foo : NSObject
{
    CFAttributedStringRef m_foo;
}
@property (nonatomic, assign) CFAttributedStringRef foo;
@end

@implementation Foo
@synthesize foo = m_foo;

- (id)initWithAttributedString:(CFAttributedStringRef)attributedString
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self == nil)
        return nil;

    if (attributedString != NULL)
    {
        self.foo = CFAttributedStringCreateCopy(NULL, attributedString);
    }

    return self;
}

- (void)dealloc
{
    if (self.foo != NULL)
        CFRelease(self.foo);

    [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

XCode warns me about potential memory leaks at both the `CFAttributedStringCreateCopy` and the `CFRelease`.  Why?

**EDIT:** If I use the member variable `m_foo` directly, it corrects the issue.  Do I have the memory management semantics of the property wrong?

Comment: You can also use ARC and toll free bridging to cast it directly to an NSAttributedString and have the memory managed for you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You cannot use property setter/getter methods with manual memory management functions like malloc, free, CFRetain, CFRelease, CFCopy, CFCreate, etc.  You must use the instance variable directly (i.e., use `m_foo` instead of `self.foo`)
2. If `foo` is a read/write property then you must provide a custom setter implementation that handles the memory management correctly.

For example, and setter that copies:

```
- (void)setFoo:(CFAttributedStringRef)newValue {

    CFAttributedStringRef oldValue = m_foo;
    if (newValue) {
        m_foo = CFAttributedStringCreateCopy(NULL, newValue);
    } else {
        m_foo = NULL;
    }

    if (oldValue) {
        CFRelease(oldValue);
    }
}
```

If `foo` does not need to be a public property then you probably want to just get rid of it and use the instance variable exclusively.